# How to add a new network connection ? -----"Network Disconnected, you are now offline"

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

My ubuntu14.04 virtual machine was installed on my Macbook air by using parallel desktop software. I have been used my ubuntu for more than 1 years but tonight it suddenly could not connect network.

After trying some methods by other posts I carelessly delete my previous connection and add a new connection which is called "Ethernet connection 1". But it still didn't work. I want to edit connections but don't know how to do it.

I just followed some instructions and tried to fix this problem. First I am sure there is no problem with my hardware since I have tried to do "ping" and it succeeded to send and receive all packet.

Then I input `ifconfig`, the result was shown as below,

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:18:52:ab  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4681 (4.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9856 (9.8 KB)  TX bytes:9856 (9.8 KB)
```

then I don't know how to do next.

Can anybody tell me how to add a new network connection?

Below is my software environment

1. host is MacBook Air
2. ubuntu version: 14.04
3. network is the university wifi
4. vm network is connected with bridge mode

Comment: If you ping and it responds, you are connected. What is the problem? Are you using the Ubuntu unity desktop, server, or something else?